# in python, how to send variable value by email

Tags: python, email

There is a variable `x` in python script, I wanna send the value of `x` by email. My code is

```
s=smtplib.SMTP('locaolhost')
s.sendmail(FROM, TO, "the answer is x")
```

But I always got the message `the answer is x` instead of `x` being the real value. How to solve this?

Comment: You use complicated libs, but then don't know how to format strings? I strongly advise you to learn the minimum before you ask...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s.sendmail(FROM, TO, "the answer is " + str(x))
```

You first convert the value of `x` into string by `str(x)`, then append `str(x)` to the end of the string `"the answer is "` by `+`.

Comment: Another question, how to make a subject for the email? now there is no subject.

Comment: You have to include the subject at the beginning of the message: For example here http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-send-mail-from-a-python-script.htm

Answer (score 5):

You can use string concatination here, as you can everywhere.

```
s.sendmail(FROM, TO, "the answer is " + x)
```

Or you can use the print format syntax:

```
s.sendmail(FROM, TO, "the answer is {}".format(x))
```

Read more: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Comment: Avoid to cast x as str() like that but use the %s formatter like in my answer.

Comment: I edited out the % operation. From the I/O manual: "Since str.format() is quite new, a lot of Python code still uses the % operator. However, because this old style of formatting will eventually be removed from the language, str.format() should generally be used."

Answer (score 1):

```
s=smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(FROM, TO, "the answer is %s" % x) # here is the change
```

You forgot the %s formatter in your string !

So :

```
x = 'hello world'
s.sendmail(FROM, TO, "the answer is x")
```

Output: `the answer is x`

And :

```
x = 'hello world'
s.sendmail(FROM, TO, "the answer is %s" % x)
```

Output: `the answer is hello world`

Answer (score 1):

Your sendmail line should be like this:

```
s.sendmail(FROM, TO, "The answer is "+x)
```